# Can the str.replace method be inside a class?

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python and trying to create a function that replaces smart quotes inside the string. A simple function with for loop seems fine but I want to overwrite the existing input. So I defined a class to overwrite the input but it seems like when I try to use the `str.replace` method, it results to attribute error. My reproducible code is as follows:

```
smart_quotes = ['“', '”', '’', '‘', '–', '—', '−', '‐']
quote_replacement = ['"', '"', "'", "'", '-', '-', '-', '-']

class Passage:
    def __init__(self, passage):
        passage = passage
    #Replace smart quotes
    def quote_replace(self):
        for i in range(len(smart_quotes)):
            self = self.replace(smart_quotes[i], quote_replacement[i])

sample = Passage('“This ‘is’ a sample string”')
```

When I try to call my method, the following error shows:

```
AttributeError: 'Passage' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Can you guys point out what am I missing?

Comment: `self.passage.replace`. You'll also have to assign the property to the instance in the init method.

Comment: The object indicated by `self` is indeed not a string. However, `self.passage` is a string. You might want to use `self.passage = self.passage.replace` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

First, you're not saving the `passage` argument to the initializer, you need to do `self.passage = passage` instead of `passage = passage`

Second, you are calling `replace` on `self` which is a `class Passage`, not a `str`. I believe you intend to call it on the `passage` from the initializer

```
class Passage:
    def __init__(self, passage):
        self.passage = passage

    #Replace smart quotes
    def quote_replace(self):
        for i in range(len(smart_quotes)):
            self.passage = self.passage.replace(smart_quotes[i], quote_replacement[i])

sample = Passage('“This ‘is’ a sample string”')
```

The organization of quote replacements here will be tough to maintain, you could instead use a `dict` to map the originals to the replacements

```
quote_replacements = {
  '“': '"', 
  '”': '"',
  '’': "'",
  '‘': "'",
  '–': '-',
  '—': '-',
  '−': '-',
  '‐': '-',
}

class Passage:
    def __init__(self, passage):
        self.passage = passage

    #Replace smart quotes
    def quote_replace(self):
        for original, replacement in quote_replacements.items():
            self.passage = self.passage.replace(original, replacement)
```

Idk your full use case, but I think you probably would be better off doing the replacement when initializing rather than calling it later

```
quote_replacements = {
  '“': '"', 
  '”': '"',
  '’': "'",
  '‘': "'",
  '–': '-',
  '—': '-',
  '−': '-',
  '‐': '-',
}

def replace_smart_quotes(passage):
    for original, replacement in quote_replacements.items():
        passage = passage.replace(original, replacement)
    return passage

class Passage:
    def __init__(self, passage):
        self.passage = replace_smart_quotes(passage)
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot the simplest rule in creating classes. Thank you very much, you actually helped me solve my other problem in improving my quote replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Or, make it much simpler with a simple mapping, and function to perform the replacements:

```
quotes = {
    '“': '"',
    '”': '"',
    '’': "'",
    '‘': "'",
    '–': "-",
    '—': "-",
    '−': "-",
    '‐': "-",
}

def quote_replace(passage):
    for search, replace in quotes.items():
        passage = passage.replace(search, replace)
    return passage

print(quote_replace('“This ‘is’ a sample string”'))
```